# A relatable riddle

Tags: riddle

> I like to be red on icons,
>   Just two taps away on iPhones.
>   Webmasters love me with passion,
>   Let's be friends in a math session!

**Hint 1**:

> The title matters.

**Hint 2**:

> The first line can be *puzzling*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say you are

> The symbol "<"

Because:

I like to be red on icons,

> You are red on the symbol of puzzling.stackexchange

Just two taps away on iPhones.

> I assume as other symbols in the other answers, you can type it in two touches on an iPhone (I don't own one so I'm not sure)

Webmasters love me with passion.

> "<" is the symbol to open a tag in html

Let's be friends in a math session!

> It is also used in maths to write "is less than" 
>  Edit: <3 is commonly used to draw a heart, which is a friendly symbol

Comment: And “relatable” because it compares 2 things  to each other

Comment: This would also have been my answer, but I do have an iphone, and < is exactly three taps away. I even went to the trouble of changing the keyboard layout to English to verify that it didn't move to the second page.  Oh well.

Answer (score 3):

Answer:

> A notification

I like to be red on icons

> On phones, SE, etc. notification count is usually a number inside a small red circle

Just two taps away on iPhones

> An iPhone notification can be dismissed with two taps

Webmasters love me with passion

> Email notifications and now browser desktop notifications keep users coming back

Let’s be friends in a math session

> Not entirely sure but perhaps a friend request in a math game?

Comment: _"Just two taps away on iPhones"_ means you can get/reach **it** with two taps, not dissmiss **it**. I guess.

Comment: Good guess, but not the answer I thought of.

Answer (score 3):

I think

> Beam

I like to be red on icons,

> The music icon is in red in Iphones. The symbol in music icon is called Beam notes.

Just two taps away on iPhones.

> Beam photos. You can beam files directly to another iOS device with iPhoto installed. I think it needs two taps.(I am a android user :P)

Webmasters love me with passion.

> It can be [Apache beam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Beam) ?

Let's be friends in a math session!

> I think this refers to [BEAM](https://www.beammath.org/mission/) (Bridge to Enter Advanced Mathematics), which is a community for creating pathways for underserved students to become scientists, mathematicians, engineers, and computer scientists.

Comment: Great guess, it's close.

Answer (score 3):

The iphone thing is probably dependent on both locale and context, but let’s try

> the slash symbol, or /

When over icons, it’s usually red, and indicates

> forbidden, not in use, out of order, and in general, “no”.

I’m writing this on an iphone, so two taps are needed, namely

> <kbd>123</kbd> and <kbd>/</kbd>.

Webmasters love it because

> the HTTP request to serve the root of any site is “GET /“. Sysadmins are also often pretty passionate about the final slash in a URL pointing to a directory: if the slash is missing, the server will usually tell the browser to try again with the slash appended, resulting in unnecessary traffic.

And of course, in a math session,

> the slash is the symbol for division.

Comment: Great guess, so close!

Comment: the last one is a bit obscure...  good guess tho!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are

> A colon (the punctuation mark)?

I like to be red on icons,

> I'm thinking in particular of a digital clock or clock icon, which often has a red colon separating from hours from minutes.

Just two taps away on iPhones.

> Similar to Bass's answer - one tap to get to the symbol keyboard, and another tap to select the : symbol itself.

Webmasters love me with passion,

> Webmasters and website code often use colons - think of http:// at the beginning of a URL, for example.

Let's be friends in a math session!

> Math uses colons to show ratios.

And the title (A Relatable Riddle)

> A ratio is a way of *relating* two quantities to one another.  In addition, writers might use a colon as a way to connect - or relate - multiple clauses in a sentence.